# Your app is uploading users Social Account information to .. without a prominent disclosure - app will be removed from Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, mobile-application, privacy-policy

I got an e-mail from Google that my app will be removed within 7 days if I don't fix the issue.
I contacted Google but I have not yet received a clear information, they are constantly sending me to review their web page( "Review Best practices for prominent disclosure" and "User Data Policy")
but I don't understand **social account information**.Because I dont use any social account in my app. Have you experienced this before? do you have any idea?

APK REQUIRES PROMINENT DISCLOSURE
Your app is uploading users' **Social Account information to** "my server web link" without a prominent disclosure. Prior to the collection and transmission, it must prominently highlight how the user data will be used, describe the type of data being collected and have the user provide affirmative consent for such use.
For further details on the valid prominent disclosure requirement, please review the “Prominent Disclosure & Consent Requirement” section under the User Data policy.

Your app is uploading users' **Social Account information to** "my server web link" without a prominent disclosure.

Comment: It is unlikely that anyone here will produce any insight relevant to your case without knowing anything about your app. Review the information provided by Google, review your app for anything that could be related to networking and user information including any libraries you use (ads? analytics?).

Comment: @teapot418 yeah it's ok , we reviewed documents but what is social account information i am actually curious about. I don't understand what social account mean

Comment: Social account usually means Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn, etc.

Comment: Hi everyone, we we fixed this issue. We import android.accounts.AccountManager class. And This issue was opened because we did not specify it in our privacy policy.

Comment: @IlkcanBs I have the same issue, but not using AccountManager class and other social media accounts in the app. How did you find AccountManager class is the issue and what did you add in your privacy policy?